# Why does this kivy code of loading a gif file work in python 3 and does not work in python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I tried to compile the following code with python 2 but I get error.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string("""
<ExampleApp>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        text: ""
        on_press: gif.anim_delay = 0.10
        on_press: gif._coreimage.anim_reset(True)

        Image:
            id: gif
            source: 'img.gif'
            center: self.parent.center
            size: 500, 500
            allow_stretch: True
            anim_delay: -1
            anim_loop: 1
""")

class ExampleApp(App, BoxLayout):
    def build(self):
        return self

if __name__ == "__main__":
   ExampleApp().run()
```

This is the error I'm getting on Windows:

```
C:\Python27\kivy-rubik-master\teste>C:\Python27\python.exe main.py

[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Vivaldo\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-02-18
_112.txt

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1

[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [
MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded

[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif
 (img_ffpyplayer ignored)

[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system

[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <3.1.0 - Build 9.17.10.4229>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Intel>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 1

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <1.40 - Intel Build 9.17.10.4229>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>

[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider

[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked

[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2

[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture img.gif

[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop

[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

After click the button i receive this error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'anim_reset'
```

Comment: Please refrain from linking a screenshot of the error and instead include it in the text of your question.

Comment: In kivy 1.10.1 with Python 2.7.15 on Linux works correctly

Comment: I will not use next error images.

Comment: I think I'll try to compile on linux.